# XML Specific node template not matching

Tags: xml, templates, xslt

I am currently trying to copy out an XML document into a new one and renaming some of the nodes as I go. My issue however is that my templates are not being hit and only the global one is:

```
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

and my specific template is (adapted for below):

```
  <xsl:template match="F">
    <G>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </G>
  </xsl:template>
```

The xml structure is similar to this however adapted due to the nature of the work :)

```
<T>
 <A>
  <B>
  </B>
  <C>
  </C>
 </A>
 <D>
  <E>Data</E>
  <F>Data</F>
 </D>
</T>
```

When running this through in VS2010 I can see it hit the line of F on the XML however is still applies the general template and not the more specific one. Any ideas why this would be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This OP has conceiled the most important fact about the XML document** -- as he tells us in a later comment, "*The XML uses a namespace*" ...

**Here is a solution to this so late-clarified question**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:x="some:namespace" xmlns="some:namespace"
 exclude-result-prefixes="x">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="x:F">
     <G>
       <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </G>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document** (based on the namespace the OP admitted...):

```
<T xmlns="some:namespace">
    <A>
        <B>   </B>
        <C>   </C>
    </A>
    <D>
        <E>Data</E>
        <F>Data</F>
    </D>
</T>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<T xmlns="some:namespace">
    <A>
        <B />
        <C />
    </A>
    <D>
        <E>Data</E>
        <G>Data</G>
    </D>
</T>
```

**Explanation**:

The problem in the original code is here:

```
  <xsl:template match="F">
```

This template matches an element `F` that is in no namespace. However all elements of the real XML document are in some undisclosed namespace -- not in no namespace. Therefore, the above template cannot match an `F` element in no namespace, because no such (`F` element in no namespace) exists.

The solution is to define the same namespace in the XSLT transformation and to have the template match an `F` element in that namespace.

Comment: Apologies for omitting the detail but my experience with XSL is rediculously small. It has solved the issue though.

Comment: @Mike: Details are important. Otherwise we could explain any problem with the bad weather.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work fine for me. I used following stylesheet :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="F">
    <G>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </G>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and ran it on your xml code, returning the following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<T>
<A>
    <B>
</B>
    <C>
</C>
</A>
<D>
    <E>Data</E>
    <G>Data</G>
</D>
```

Whicj looks like the result you want. So can you give a bit more info on where things go wrong ?

Comment: When running the XSLT with a breakpoint in VS2010 it reaches the node I am looking for and just reads it with the default template. Also copied in your template and tried that receiving the same issue. The XML uses a namespace, would this have any effect on the process? I have declared the ns the same in the xslt as in the xml im transforming so wouldn't think it's that

Comment: @Mike: You have hidden from us one most important information -- that the nodes are in a namespace (default?). Even for this you deserve a downvote (just saying). Please, edit the question and provide a real XML document, so that people then can repro the problem themselves!

Comment: Not the default namespace, if I had a clue it was important I would of said it, clearly its going to be difficult with getting a response to this as I can't disclose the actual data as it is work related and therefore confidential. Please feel free to downvote me if you feel required its a nice welcome to the site :) Is it likely the namespace is what is causing the issue?

Comment: @Mike: Of course -- the namespace *is* the reason. See my answer.